# wordpress if get_categories value larger/smaller

Tags: wordpress

i have code in category.php

```
<?php $getcatid = get_query_var('cat'); ?>
<?php $args = array('child_of' => ''.$getcatid.'', 'parent' => ''.$getcatid.'', 'hide_empty' => 0);?>
<?php $categories = get_categories($args); foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>
<?php $getid = $cat->cat_ID; ?>
```

how to check quantity subcategory value as:

`if $categories < 4 ($getcatid had smaller 4 sub)` echo code loop

`else (if $categories > 4 )` echo code loop

Any idea. Thanks

Comment: i user code `<?php if ($categories < 4) { ?>
<?php echo 'Category < 4'; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php echo 'Else Category'; ?>
<?php } ?>` and all category echo Else Category. How to check value sub category < 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you retrieve your categories with `get_categories` you can easily run `count()` on the result, to check how many entries there are. You can then use that number for your comparison.

Probably like this (untested):

```
 <?php 
   // stripped your code out
   $categories = get_categories($args);

   if(count($categories) > 4) { }
   else { }
 ?>
```